# What is the f(x) equation for the wave ('jazz stripe') of a Vans Shoes?

Tags: plane-curves

I'm curious about how to find an `f(x)` equation for the "wave" logo of the Vans Shoes. It's a simple 1-dimensional wave. I've been thinking about this for a month and couldn't get the answer. Here's an image for a reference: 
[vans' wave](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dd3wv.jpg)

[image]

Could someone possibly explain how to get that `f(x)` equation?

Comment: While I'm sure someone will come up with an acceptable formula, it's mathematically important to know that there isn't just one formula that will work; lots of functions will have graphs shaped like that wave.

Comment: What types of curves have you thought of using?

Comment: My first guess would be a rounded [tractrix](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Tractrix.html), sometimes called a HundKurve, because it's the curve a dog would follow if he's on a leash but striving to reach a bone too far from the straight path he is meant to be on.

Answer (score 0):

There are too many possibilities to play with.. and is quite subjective, even as a flat 3D curve approximation.

Can rotate the given curve here a bit and adjust $x$ domain. Parametric plot given can be put into $y=f(x)$ form.

[image: Shoe Curve]